# My kivy app crushes when label or text input has letter 'w' in the text field

Tags: python, label, kivy-language, textinput, boxlayout

Anytime I have letter 'w'(lower case) in the text field of a TextInput or Label, the whole application crushes with "virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked" error. Surprisingly, all keys work including 'W'(upper case). below is my code. please note the **returnedWidget** is built on a BoxLayout widget.

```
<returnedWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput: 
        id: my_input
        font_size: 150
        size_hint_y: None
        height:200
        text: 'w'
    FloatLayout:
        Scatter:
            Label:
                text: 'w'
                font_size: 150
```

I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be font_size related bug. With font_size: 150 or 160 it crashes. But for example with 140, 170, 180 it works fine.

I submitted following issue: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8108

Based on [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7914) the workaround is to add on top of your python script:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'pil'
```

The second working workaround is to manually update library:

```
venv\share\sdl2\bin\SDL2_ttf.dll
```

from 2.0.18 to latest one 2.20.1:
https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases/download/release-2.20.1/SDL2_ttf-2.20.1-win32-x64.zip

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases

I hope Kivy will upgrade it's dependent library SDL_ttf soon.

Comment: Your first suggestion of font size 140, 170, 180 did not work for me but the workaround of adding below to my python script worked fine. Thanks.


import os
os.environ['KIVY_TEXT'] = 'pil'

Comment: It may also depend on window/widget size. In my case the same font size behave same on Win10 and Win11. It's a SDL2_ttf.dll v2.0.18 bug solved in latest SDL_ttf release, which hopefully will be used as dependency in next Kivy release. Based on github comment latest Kivy 2.2.0.dev0 is already fixed but I wasn't able to upgrade Kivy based on sources. I'll probably wait for next final Kivy release. Till then, workaround can be used.